# MySQL WHERE LIKE substring

Tags: php, mysql

I realise the title of this question may scream "duplicate" but I don't think it is (at least if it is, I haven't seen it).

I am currently storing a list separated by commas in the database like `1,3,5,6,13` but when I do `SELECT id FROM users WHERE additional_usergroups LIKE '%3%'` both `3` and `13` show up.

Is there a way round this?

**EDIT**
I'm looking for only **3** to show up in the result, sorry for being so vague with the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes - properly normalize your database. (Or use FIND_IN_SET, if you want to keep the mess you have right now at any cost ...)

Comment: you want exact 3 in your result?

Comment: Yes, I only want 3 to show up, @a_a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why RDBMS have normalization guidelines.  I encourage you to read about normalization and why values in databases should be singular.

But, a way around this would be including every possibility of just 3:

```
additional_usergroups LIKE '3' 
OR additional_usergroups LIKE '%,3,%'
OR additional_usergroups LIKE '3,%'
OR additional_usergroups LIKE '%,3'
```

As @CBroe pointed out, MySQL appears to have a [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to handle this:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', additional_usergroups) > 0
```

However, normalization is still recommended for a RDBMS.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE additional_usergroups LIKE '3%'
```

the '%' means grab whatever you can which is why its used for search features so frequently.  if you remove it you will only grab numbers that begin with 3, so 3,31,312 etc.

Comment: Thanks @Cody but this still wouldn't be useful to me because if I was to have `31` it would pickup that and I wouldn't want it.

Comment: if you just want the '3' then get rid of both '%'. 

like '3'

Comment: @Cody Then you won't find anything, since the value of the field is "3,1,2,31,4" and not just "3".

Comment: SQL would pull the entire row no matter what right? I dont understand how you would be just getting the 3,13

Comment: You should use a string split to and put the comma separated values inside a temporary table and that will resolve your problem